# Voltage Gain for Driver in Class AB Amplifier

Tags: driver, push-pull, biasing

Can anyone tell me how to calculate the Voltage gain for Q3 in the following schematic ?

Is it the same method (or partially modified) like the one used for Class A amplifiers for Voltage gain calculation? 
Av = R1/R2 ?

[image]

Comment: R1 is loaded (in parallel with) the boosted load impedance: In this case, \$ R3  \   \beta_{Q1} \$. Thus, AC gain will be reduced from 1000/100

Comment: Q3 voltage gain is R1/R2 or less (if Q1 and Q2 haven't sufficient beta).